# Subqueries in Druid - Cannot build plan for query

Tags: sql, join, subquery, apache-superset, druid

I'm trying to write a SQL query in Druid/Superset, which performs a 'GROUP BY' for two different time intervals (let's say last 7 days and last 30 days) on data from the same table and join both results. For example, the result of the first GROUP BY contains the columns 'col1, col2, col3, freq1' (freq1 is the count resulting from the aggregation). The second result contains the columns 'col1, col2, col3, freq2'. I would like to get the following output: 'col1, col2, col3, freq1, freq2'. The problem is, that Druid does not fully support joins. I have tried it like this:

```
WITH
    interval1 AS
       (
            SELECT col1, col2, col3, COUNT(*) AS freq
            FROM pv_sample
            WHERE __time >= TIME_SHIFT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'P1D', -7)
                AND __time <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
            LIMIT 10
        ),
    interval2 AS
        (
            SELECT col1, col2, col3, COUNT(*) AS freq
            FROM pv_sample
            WHERE __time >= TIME_SHIFT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'P1D', -30)
                AND __time <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
            LIMIT 10
        )
SELECT i1.col1, i1.col2, i1.col3, i1.freq AS freq1, i2.freq AS freq2
FROM interval1 i1, interval2 i2
WHERE i1.col1 = i2.col1 AND
    i1.col2 = i2.col2 AND
    i1.col3 = i2.col3
```

The result was:

> Unknown exception (io.druid.java.util.common.ISE): Cannot build plan for query: `WITH interval1 AS ( SELECT ...`

Could somebody give me a hint, what is wrong with my code and how could I solve my problem?